# How to add Shutdown button to LXPanel and make it work?

Tags: shutdown, panel, logout, button

I cannot seem to be able to add a shutdown button to my LXPanel. In `/usr/share/applications` there is a Shutdown (lubuntu-logout.desktop) containing  the line `Exec=lubuntu-logout` but it would not run.

It contains the following

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shutdown
Comment=Shutdown or Reboot
Icon=system-shutdown-panel
Exec=lubuntu-logout
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Utility;Settings;System;GTK
NoDisplay=false
```

In `usr/bin` there is a shell script called `lubuntu-logout`:

```
#!/bin/sh
lxsession-logout --banner "/usr/share/lubuntu/images/logout-banner.png" --side=top
```

Creating a desktop file that will contain the line `Exec=lxsession-logout` should also work. But it does not!

Trying to make it executable, trying to find permissions in pcmanfm - properties:

[image]

In Thunar I can find the settings to make it executable:

[image]

But then running it I get

[image]

How should I edit it to make it run and then visible in menus so to add it to the panel?

**OR: What is the correct content of the shutdown.desktop file?**

Comment: Do you have this package installed? `lubuntu-default-settings`

Comment: @Uri Herrera - `lubuntu-default-settings` 0.29 was installed all this time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a file that works.

Used the line `Exec=/usr/bin/lxsession-logout`.

Called the file `Shutdown-lubuntu.desktop` with these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ShutdownLubuntu
Comment=Shutdown or Reboot
Icon=system-shutdown-panel
Exec=/usr/bin/lxsession-logout
Categories=GTK;System;Settings;
Type=Application
```

and put it in `usr/share/applications`.
This made it appear in main menu under System Tools and could be added in lxpanel in an application launch bar.

Answer (score 2):

I opened the config file:

```
gnome-open ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel
```

and added these lines at the end:

```
Plugin {
    type = launchbar
    Config {
      Button {
            id=/usr/share/applications/lubuntu-logout.desktop  
      }
    }
}
```

This added the logout menu to the lxpanel.